# Pager indcater in Android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, composable

I am new with android Compose
Can Anyone told me if there any way to implement Page indcater in compose without third library ?
I am using material design 3
I have tried many solutions
But its Dublicated

I try a way with state pager but now its Dublicated

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/q/73416996/7666442

Comment: i tried it but when i use it with lazyRow
its still go to 1 -2 index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts to find an effective solution
I found two ways

The first:
[Jetpack Compose animated pager dots indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73416996/jetpack-compose-animated-pager-dots-indicator?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The Second :
[Pager indicator for compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73221894/pager-indicator-for-compose)

but you will face some issue
about PagerState Class which now is duplicated
so you Can use rememberPagerState

```
fun PageIndicatorSample() {
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {

    Spacer(Modifier.height(40.dp))
    val pagerState1 = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    PagerIndicatornew(pagerState = pagerState1, indicatorCount = getAllData.size) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            pagerState1.scrollToPage(it)
        }

    }

    HorizontalPager(
        pageCount = getAllData.size,
        state = pagerState1,
    ) {
        // Here You Add what compose You Want... this is just example
        Card(getAllData[it])
    }
  }
 }
```

**For Pager indicator**

```
  @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
 @Composable
 fun PagerIndicatornew(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
pagerState: PagerState,
indicatorCount: Int = 5,
indicatorSize: Dp = 16.dp,
indicatorShape: Shape = CircleShape,
space: Dp = 8.dp,
activeColor: Color = Color(0xffEC407A),
inActiveColor: Color = Color.LightGray,
onClick: ((Int) -> Unit)? = null) {
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
val totalWidth: Dp = indicatorSize * indicatorCount + space * (indicatorCount - 1)
val widthInPx = LocalDensity.current.run { indicatorSize.toPx() }
val currentItem by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        pagerState.currentPage
    }
}
val itemCount = indicatorCount
LaunchedEffect(key1 = currentItem) {
    val viewportSize = listState.layoutInfo.viewportSize
    listState.animateScrollToItem(
        currentItem,
        (widthInPx / 2 - viewportSize.width / 2).toInt()
    )
}
LazyRow(
    modifier = modifier.width(totalWidth),
    state = listState,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = space),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space),
    userScrollEnabled = false
) {

    items(itemCount) { index ->

        val isSelected = (index == currentItem)

        // Index of item in center when odd number of indicators are set
        // for 5 indicators this is 2nd indicator place
        val centerItemIndex = indicatorCount / 2

        val right1 =
            (currentItem < centerItemIndex &&
                    index >= indicatorCount - 1)

        val right2 =
            (currentItem >= centerItemIndex &&
                    index >= currentItem + centerItemIndex &&
                    index <= itemCount - centerItemIndex + 1)
        val isRightEdgeItem = right1 || right2

        // Check if this item's distance to center item is smaller than half size of
        // the indicator count when current indicator at the center or
        // when we reach the end of list. End of the list only one item is on edge
        // with 10 items and 7 indicators
        // 7-3= 4th item can be the first valid left edge item and
        val isLeftEdgeItem =
            index <= currentItem - centerItemIndex &&
                    currentItem > centerItemIndex &&
                    index < itemCount - indicatorCount + 1

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .graphicsLayer {
                    val scale = if (isSelected) {
                        1f
                    } else if (isLeftEdgeItem || isRightEdgeItem) {
                        .5f
                    } else {
                        .8f
                    }
                    scaleX = scale
                    scaleY = scale

                }

                .clip(indicatorShape)
                .size(indicatorSize)
                .background(
                    if (isSelected) activeColor else inActiveColor,
                    indicatorShape
                )
                .then(
                    if (onClick != null) {
                        Modifier
                            .clickable {
                                onClick.invoke(index)
                            }
                    } else Modifier
                )
            )
          }
         }
      }
```

> NOTE: the first solution has some issues with indexing
> so I prefer the Second  one

Answer (score 0):

Look at [accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) source code and customize it if you need or better use third-party lib